# Как привести объект, который уже был упакован, в примитивный тип в Java?

Tags: java, объекты, примитивы, autoboxing

Нуб. Разбираюсь в  java-core. Например, есть код:

```
        int i = 5;
        Integer i = new Integer(i);
```

И после желаю управление переменной i(не как с объектом, а как с примитивом), как до упаковки, т.е. либо есть что-то, чего я не знаю либо нельзя.
p.s. : гуглил, в англоязычном тоже гуглил: выдаёт про что-то javascript .

Comment: То, что приведено в вопросе ужЕ не валидно, т.к. нельзя объявить переменную другого типа с тем же именем

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский , из-за  этого не добавили возможность обратно распаковывать из обьекта в примитив?

Comment: Объектное представление спокойно автоматически распаковывается когда это делают правильно. А ты и запаковыаешь-то неправильно.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский так точно, есть метод toString(), он например при простом выводе в консоль вызывается автоматически, но я интересовался про другой способ управлять этими данными путем перевода обратно в примитив.

Comment: `int test = new Integer(666);`  вполне себе работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Integer` - это неизменяемый объект. Нельзя изменить то `int` значение, которое внутри содержится. Только создать новый объект.
2. Для создания `Integer` лучше использовать `valueOf` вместо конструктора: `Integer.valueOf(5)`. Конструктор (вызываемый при `new`) является deprecated с Java 9.
3. Для получения обратно `int` можно использовать метод `intValue`: `Integer.valueOf(5).intValue()` вернёт `5`.